# C instruction is being reordered when cin cout and gets is used consecutively

Tags: c++, cin, gets

Does anyone knows why C instruction is being reordered when cin cout and gets is used consecutively here?
I am using Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char a[10],b;
    for(;;){
        cout<<"\ncin>>b:";
        cin>>b;
        cout<<"gets(a):";
        gets(a);
        cout<<"cout<<a<<b:"<<a<<" "<<b<<"\n\n";
    }
}
```

I got an output like:

```
cin>>b:132
gets(a):cout<<a<<b:32 1


cin>>b:465
gets(a):cout<<a<<b:65 4


cin>>b:312242
gets(a):cout<<a<<b:12242 3


cin>>b:1
gets(a):cout<<a<<b: 1

cin>>b:
```

It seemed like some input for cin was passed in gets.. and it also appears that instructions were reordered like:

```
cin>>b;
gets(a);
cout<<"gets(a):";
```

instead of,

```
cin>>b;
cout<<"gets(a):";
gets(a);
```

Comment: Please, learn to format text here and do not try to use bbcode or whatever. Here you format code by selecting it and hitting CTRL-K or manually by leaving a blank line before, and indenting it with four spaces.

Comment: And please, try using a *real* IDE with a *real* compiler. Dev-C++ hasn't been updated for something like 4 years, and even back when it *was* maintained, it was still buggy, lacked basic features, and was basically useless. There are many *free* alternatives that are actually worth using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cin>>b read just a character, leaving the rest of the input to be read by later input operation.  So gets sill has something to read and don't block.

At the first `cin >> b`, there is no input available.  You enter '132\n' (input from terminal is usually made line by line) in a buffer and just get the 1 out of it.  gets reads the next characters 32 and the \n which terminates gets.  It doesn't need to read something more from the terminal.

Comment: but why is it that gets() is skipped when I input only 1 character in the cin>>b?

Comment: @prinzrainer: when you type `1`, you actually enter `"1\n"`, that's 2 characters. `gets()` will read `"\n"`, and thus returns an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing has been re-ordered.

your input from keyboard has been send only when you pressed enter. At that time, there have been enough data to execute the `cin<<b`, the following `cout`, then to complete the `gets(a)`.

In others words, the execution of `cin<<b` is suspended to the reception of a char. But that char is not send to the program until you pressed 'Enter' (this is because of your terminal settings). When you press 'Enter', the first char is received by `cin<<b` and the remaining is buffered. `cout` executes, and when it is the turn of `gets(a)`, the buffer delivers the remaining chars included the carriage return, so `gets(a)` completes as well, with the data you entered to complete the `cin<<b` instruction.

Try to simply press enter for the `cin<<b` to complete, then you'll see the `cout`, and then you will have the `gets(a)` waiting for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

While not really answering your question...

The idiomatic way in C++ would rather be to use [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/). It's an accident of history that does not make it part of the `iostream` interface directly, but it really is **the** function to use for inputs.

Shameless plug from the website:

```
// getline with strings
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main () {
  std::string str;
  std::cout << "Please enter full name: ";
  getline (std::cin,str);
  std::cout << "Thank you, " << str << ".\n";
}
```

The main advantage of `getline`, in this version, is that it reads up until it encounters a line-ending character.

You can specify your own set of "line-ending" characters in the overload accepting a third parameter, to make it stop on commas or colons, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The code isn't reordered, but std::cout is buffered so the string doesn't appear immediately on your display. Therefore gets(a) will be executed with the output still in the buffer.

You can add a <<flush after the output string to make cout flush it's buffer.

When you use std::cin, it knows how to tell std::cout to flush the buffer before the input  starts, so you don't have to.